# Highchart google presentation

Tags: r, highcharts

I have some charts created with highcharter in R.

I want to insert these charts into google presentation slides.

Is there any way of adding these charts to google slides keeping the interactivity features as opposed to plain insert image PNG format?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and relatively simple. It's well documented in rmarkdown.rstudio.com/formats.html. Hope you find what you want ;)

Comment: Thanks! I will do so. Btw wasn't expecting a response from the author :)